# Check if piece of String is there in string java

Tags: java, android, string

i am looking for a piece of code which can search for a string in a string.

```
String mainSTR = "It is Wednesday";
```

So i need a code that will return true if i search

`"Day"` or `"day"` or `"DAY"`  in `mainSTR`.

I tried methods like

```
mainSTR.contains("")
```

and

```
mainSTR.IndexOf("") > -1
```

are not working for me

Thanks :)

Comment: You want to check for `Day`, then why are you passing empty string in `contains`?

Comment: Are you only looking for "Day", "day", and "DAY" or are things like "dAY" and "DaY" acceptable?

Comment: Thanks but contains not working for me i tried those methods i mentioned

Comment: @loveeSindh: Show your actual code with `contains()` which does not work. If you do it the way posted in all of the answers, it will work. You can use the [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17818593/edit) button below your question.

Comment: @loveeSindh please stop saying "not working" and instead try to explain **exactly** how it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `mainSTR` is a really long String, this approach may be more efficient:

```
String mainSTR = "It is Wednesday";
String toSearch = "Day";
boolean found = Pattern.compile(toSearch, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(mainSTR).find();
```

the last line is equivalent to

```
boolean found = Pattern.compile("(?i)" + toSearch).matcher(mainSTR).find();
```

But beware that `toSearch` may not contain regex meta characters if you do it this way.

Comment: if mainSTR = "+91111111189";
 toSearch = "89"

will it still work in that case because i just got an error when i used this code.

Comment: @loveeSindh: it would work without a problem (even tested it to be sure). What kind of error did you get??

Comment: but you warned me about toSearch. so even mainSTR cant contain regex meta character. so any way to ignore it?

Comment: @loveeSindh: No, `toSearch` can't contain regex metacharacters, `mainSTR` can. To avoid it, you can use `Pattern.quote()` but it won't be case insensitive anymore. (I edited my previous comment).

Comment: Ok now it is not getting any kind of error but it is now working in the case if i have number in mainSTR like i mentioned in first comment. the found remains false only.

Comment: @loveeSindh: I can not help you further if you don't post your actual code (in your question above).

Answer (score 2):

Well one can't expect such question from and Android Developer. Anyhow, for finding any word in String, you can use Java method

```
String mainSTR = "It is Wednesday";
String findThis = "DaY";

if(mainSTR.toLowerCase().contains(findThis.toLowerCase()))
{
   System.out.println("true: Day found");
}
else
   System.out.println("false: Day not found");
```

Comment: i agree but contain is not working. i tried many times it is not working that's why i asked for this anyways thanks  but it didn't helped..

Comment: can you show the actual code in which this code snipet won't work?

Answer (score 0):

What you can use here is a one way - canonicalising function. toLowerCase (or toUpperCase) is one such helper.

```
mainSTR.toLowerCase().contains("day");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mainSTR.toUpperCase().contains("day".toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String days = "day";//or "Day" or "DAY"
mainSTR.toLowerCase().contains(days.toLowerCase());
```

**Ps:** for such comparison, you should prefer `toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)` or `toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)` which give you **locale insensitive** strings.

And [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) is what javaDoc has to say about it.

> Note: This method is locale sensitive, and may produce unexpected
>   results if used for strings that are intended to be interpreted locale
>   independently. Examples are programming language identifiers, protocol
>   keys, and HTML tags. For instance, "TITLE".toLowerCase() in a Turkish
>   locale returns "t?tle", where '?' is the LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I
>   character. To obtain correct results for locale insensitive strings,
>   use toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).

Comment: JavaDoc says `toLowerCase()` uses the default locale, the same with `toUpperCase()`. Can you provide a source of what you are saying?

Comment: @jlordo http://javapapers.com/core-java/javas-tolowercase-has-got-a-surprise-for-you/

Comment: @ay89: it says "_It performs the case conversion with respect to your Locale_", that is true. But `toUpperCase()` does the same thing, so there is no difference. (P.S. I am not the downvoter)

Comment: @jlordo also read the docs again, there is something more in the description.

Comment: @ay89: yes, it says the same thing in docs of `toUpperCase()`. So there is not a preferable one, both are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:

`mainSTR.toUpperCase().contains(day.toUpperCase());`

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
   String mainStr="It is Wednesday";
   System.out.println(mainStr.toLowerCase().contains("wed".toLowerCase()));
```